# Double underscore for configurations in DotNetCore 3.1 doesn't seem to work as I was expecting

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to get double underscore for configurations to work in ASP.Net core 3.1 as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables

I've written some code for configurations that does this manually

1. check Env Var
2. check AppSettings...json files

but I saw that in .net 3.1 this is supposed to be supported by default with one caveat around hierarchal settings on unix platforms. In this case you can't use this syntax

```cs
Configuration["SomeSection:SomeConfig"]
```

to resolve this environment variable

```sh
## Environment Var
SomeConfig:SomeConfig
```

Because linux doesn't support colons in Env Var names. This would however work if code was deployed to a windows machine. So instead .net seems to indicate you can use this syntax

```cs
Configuration["SomeSection__SomeConfig"]
```

which will resolve any of the following configurations

```js
// AppSettings...json
{
   "SomeSection" {
      "SomeConfig": "some value"
   }
}
```

or

```sh
# Environment Var on linux
SomeConfig__SomeConfig
```

or

```sh
// Environment Var on windows
SomeConfig:SomeConfig
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
Note that I know the answer to this questions and will happily answer it if it's is reopened.

Comment: It isn't fully clear, which problem do you have right now and what is wrong with code above

Comment: `Configuration["SomeSection:SomeConfig"]` doesn't access an environment variable, it retrieves the `SomeConfig` setting from the `SomeSection` section, no matter where this comes from. The values are provided by config providers that may load the settings from files, databases, the command line, services etc. So what you seem to ask is **only** how the environment variable provider works in Linux and how env variable names are mapped to configuration settings

Comment: According to the docs you link to, the environment variable named `SomeSection__SomeConfig` should work on all platforms

Answer (score 8):

I had misunderstood the documentation. The way it works is that if you use this code in your `Startup.cs`

```
Configuration["SomeSection:SomeConfig"]
```

it will correctly resolve

```
// AppSettings...json
{
   "SomeSection" {
      "SomeConfig": "some value"
   }
}
```

from your various `appsettings*.json` files.

However, if you define an environment variable with the name `SomeSection:SomeConfig` that will be used instead of the `appsettings.json` value which is a great feature. This is often desirable when running the app in a docker container.

However, if are on a Linux operation system it's not possible to create an environment variable with the name `SomeSection:SomeConfig`. So if you are on Linux machine or in a Linux container, instead if you name your environment variable `SomeSection__SomeConfig` with a `__` (double underscore) instead of a `:` then you could access like below:

```
Configuration["SomeSection:SomeConfig"]
```

Comment: Double undscore in theory is multi platform

Comment: Even though I'm using double underscore on my user-secrets, it still doesn't resolve when I try using `builder.Configuration["IdentityServerConfiguration:Authority"]`